# Image src not working in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a function,

```
function showimage(a)
    {
        $("#lightboxholder").show("fast");
        $('#lightboximage').attr('src', 'images/demo/190x90.gif');
    }
```

when i go to localhost/svce and view in gallery.php, it doesnt show me the image, however if i replace `$('#lightboximage').attr('src', 'images/demo/190x90.gif');` by `$('#lightboximage').attr('src', 'http://localhost/svce/images/demo/190x90.gif');`
then it shows me the image, sorry for my bad english, thanks

Comment: Open up your F12 developer tools and check your Network tab; it's likely your path is wrong and the image isn't being found.

Comment: try this $('#lightboximage').attr('src', '../images/demo/190x90.gif');

Comment: Try `attr('src', '../images/demo/190x90.gif');
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're changing the `src` to a relative URL. So if your current page is `http://localhost/foo/bar`, the browser will try to find the image at `http://localhost/foo/bar/images/demo/190x90.gif`. Use an absolute URL, like `/svce/images/demo/190x90.gif`.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
function showimage(a)
{
       $("#lightboxholder").show("fast");
       $('#lightboximage').attr('src', '../images/demo/190x90.gif');
}
```

Note the "/" before images/demo....

Answer (score 1):

The problem is relative url - it's always a challenge for me too

Try these

```
$('#lightboximage').attr('src', '../images/demo/190x90.gif');
```

or

```
$('#lightboximage').attr('src', '../../images/demo/190x90.gif');
```

As you move from page to page, relative url will change, but absolute won't